# Screen session running as root? (it shouldn't be) node.js

Tags: permissions, gnu-screen, iptables

```
cd /serv  
screen -R node  
{in the screen}  
node test.js  
C^a d
```

initially,

```
ls -l /dev/pts  
total 0  
crw--w---- 1 tick-tock tty 136, 0 2011-04-19 16:41 0  
crw--w---- 1 tick-tock tty 136, 1 2011-04-19 16:41 1
```

but after just a few seconds

```
ls -l /dev/pts  
total 0  
crw--w---- 1 tick-tock tty 136, 0 2011-04-19 16:47 0  
crw--w---- 1 root      tty 136, 1 2011-02-21 20:00 1
```

How is the screen's terminal getting switched to root? Does this mean the node server is actually running with root permissions? It shouldn't be. The only other factor that might be an issue is that iptables forwards port 80 to port 8000 where the node server listens, so it doesn't have to run as root. I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this, perhaps I should ask in a node.js community?

I have not su root or done any sudo commands beforehand, either.

Comment: I find the date change on `/dev/pts/1` also strange. This doesn't mean node.js is running as root (it can't be unless it's setuid root, and that has absolutely nothing to do with the port forwarding). What OS is this? Is there any virtualization, SELinux or other element worth mentioning? Are there other users on this machine?

Comment: what's also pretty strange is the date going back to Feb. 21st.

Comment: This smacks of something fundamentally wrong, like a compromised system and you're tracking the effect of ghosts on the woodwork of a house. I don't know exactly what to say to look for, but we aren't seeing the whole picture yet.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, it is a VPS. There is one other user it's just an account for a friend of mine, he doesn't do anything on the box and I know his pass if I need to do anything as him. There's nothing else running either, and no it looks like node isn't running as root so I dunno what is up with that terminal. Here's the output of htop http://pastebin.com/EHvDXXQp

Answer (score 1):

Your system, once `screen` detaches, destroys the `pts`, and for some reason recreates it, if I understand correctly how `udev` is handling things on your system.

`udev` is the subsystem that controls the creation and destruction of devices in /dev, which is a dynamically generated filesystem. `pts` creation/destruction is handled by `ptmx`, which is used to create pseudo-terminal master/slave pairs. `pts/*` is the slave of the respective `PTM`, or pseudo-terminal master. As such, any permissions modifications that you see are a direct result of the destruction and creation of said device nodes, rather than *modification*. As for the date of the file, since the device nodes are clones, it's likely that the original used to create these nodes had a creation date of the time that you see in your `ls` output.

- `man ptmx` -- Describes how ptmx creates new pts pseudo terminal device nodes.

What I don't understand is why there is a difference between how your system behaves versus how mine behaves with regard to `/dev/pts/`*. I do not experience perceived perms changes to devices; They either disappear entirely which is as it should be, or the perms do not change regardless of my actions (e.g., detaching screen, the device stays, and does not get destroyed/recreated.). Not only that, but the dates associated with my newly created `pts/*` devices are the current date.

One possibility is that the VPS you're using has something to do with this behavior. For example, I can't perform a dist-upgrade on my VPS, since the system they utilize only allows for one kernel version, the one they've hacked and put in place. The kind of restrictions that prevent you from updating your own kernel could also impact the functionality of other sub-systems. That's just speculation though, but it would make sense.

It could also just be a difference in how udev is configured.

Revision 3, with a lot of help from Gilles. ;)

Comment: The kernel is not going to change the permissions of a file of its own accord, even the file is a device node. (The kernel does, however, choose the owner and permissions of a `/dev/pts/*` node *when it is created*.)

Comment: Gilles, we were both wrong. The kernel doesn't make these mods directly, thank you for the correction. But permissions on device nodes *are modified occasionally by other processes, after initialization*.

Comment: I don't see where in your write-up you've found that something would be changing the permissions on `/dev/pts/*`. The device entry disappears when it stops being used, and a *new* one is created when needed. Unlike the old `/dev/pty*`, these entries are not reused, AFAIK.

Comment: *sigh* .. I guess you're right again. Thanks for challenging my understanding of this ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Screen has several compile time options, one of them is multi-user mode. If installed in this mode screen is usually installed with suid root. See [multiuser mode docs](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser). Is yours installed this way? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/screen`?